# Question about File Permissions?

Tags: permissions

If I created a new application and copied it to the directory `/usr/local/bin`, what are the rights accorded to "others" and "group" ? I think I get all the rights so it should be `7--` but I don't know if they get full rights (`777`) or not.

Comment: This almost could get a "opinion" flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are usually set to the original permissions minus the user's umask (usually `002`, `022` for root).

Usually because this depends on the tool used for copying (the above applies e.g. to `cp` and to Files, but I guess that any tool will follow this convention).

So unless you explicitly preserve the original permissions e.g. by copying using `cp -p`, permissions will be by all odds set to the original permissions minus the user's umask, i.e. users not the owner of the file or in the file's group will lose write permissions if they have it (if the user copying the file is a regular user) and users not the owner of the file will lose write permissions if they have it (if the user copying the file is root).